# Heroku - Net::SMTPAuthenticationError 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, heroku, gmail

I am getting this mail at Heroku when I try to send an e-mail. I deployed my app from localhost, where everything works fine, but here I am getting this error.

Where could be a problem?

Thanks, M.

Comment: How are you sending the email? With Heroku you will need to use an external mail server such as Gmail to do the sending. Alternatively their sendgrid addon might be an easier approach.